# Extra chararcters when writing to a file from a struct

Tags: c++, file, character

I have a class Unit. An object of this class has name, id, budget and other stuff. I want to save the name and the budget in a .txt file at position (i-1). I created struct called Unit2:

```
struct Unit2{

    string name;
    int budget;
};
```

My file.write function:

```
void writeBudgets(Unit name,int i) {
    ofstream file("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\budgets.txt");
    Unit2 p;
    p.name  = name.getName();        //get name from the class Unit
    p.budget = name.getBudget();     //same for budget
    file.seekp((i-1)*sizeof(Unit2));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&p),sizeof(Unit2));
    file.close();
}
```

In the main I create object of Unit "a" with name "asd" and budget 120. When I use writeBudgets function an extra characters are added to my file. For example `writeBudgets(a,2);` gives me this `hÆPasd ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ      Œ` .What should I do?

Comment: Make sure your string is null terminated (i.e append \0 at the end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write a `std::string` like that to a file, as the `std::string` object doesn't have the actual string inside itself, but a pointer to the string together with its length.

What you should do is learn more about the C++ [input/output](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) library, then you can make a custom output operator `<<` for your structure.

---

You make a custom `operator<<` function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Unit2& unit)
{
    // Write the number
    os << unit.budget;

    // And finally write the actual string
    os << unit.name << '\n';

    return os;
}
```

With the above function, you can now do e.g.

```
Unit2 myUnit = { "Some Name", 123 };
std::cout << myUnit;
```

and it will print on the standard output

```
123 Some Name
```

To read the structure, you make a corresponding input operator function:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Unit2& unit)
{
    // Read the number
    is >> unit.budget;

    // The remainder of the line is the name, use std::getline to read it
    std::getline(is, unit.name);

    return is;
}
```

Comment: How can i write at least the budget at specific position with "<<" operator?I tried seekp but it is not working.For example,I have `Unit a("asd",120),b("dsa",20);` and if I use `writeBudgets(a,2);
 writeBudgets(b,1);` where writeBudgets is `void writeBudgets(Unit name,int i){
                  ofstream file("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\budgets.txt",ios::app);
 file.seekp((i-1)*(sizeof(int)+1),ios::beg);
    file << name.getBudget()<<" ";
 file.close();
}` I get `120 20` in the file not `20 120` as I want.

Comment: @user3163546 Updated my answer with some example output and input operators

Comment: `std::getline(is >> std::ws, unit.name)` - `std::getline()` doesn't skip leading whitespace.